# Maclaurin series involving an elliptic integral

Tags: special-functions, taylor-expansion

I have been asked to find the Maclaurin series expansion of a term involving an elliptic integral, I would be grateful for any help as I am unsure as to how to even start this question.
The term I have to expand is
(4/pi)* K (sin(x)) , in which K(sin(x)) represents a complete elliptic integral of the first kind with modulus sin(x).

Thanks in advance =D

Comment: Elliptic integrals are not elliptic functions.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) has the MacLaurin expansion of the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward but tedious route involves [composing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Composition_of_series) the two Maclaurin series

$$\begin{align*}
\frac2{\pi}K(m)&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2k}{k}^2\left(\frac{m}{16}\right)^k\\
\sin^2 \alpha&=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{k-1} \alpha^k}{k!}\cos\frac{k\pi}{2}
\end{align*}$$

or equivalently, using the [Faà di Bruno formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Formal_power_series_version) (e.g. via the Bell polynomials) to generate the coefficients.